# How to divide the cell into multiple cells?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I have one csv file and first and third column we have date format as 1219376117 like first four digits is days(xxxx), hours(yy), minutes(zz), second(ss) as xxxxyyzzss respectively. Everything is in one cell, so how can I separate it?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('SensorsAP_example.csv')
print (df)


## Splitting the data sets
#df = pd.DataFrame({"Time stamp":["unchange"],"time_tow":["Days, hours, minutes, seconds"]})
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the way is to first try and apply this to a simple string, which you can extend.
E.g

```
s="1219376117"
days,hours,minutes,seconds=s[:4],s[4:6],s[6:8],s[8:]
```

Post that you can leverage [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'timestamp':["1219376117","1219376118"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

def split_timestamp(s):
   days,hours,minutes,seconds=s[:4],s[4:6],s[6:8],s[8:]
   return pd.Series([days,hours,minutes,seconds])
df[["days","hours","minutes","seconds"]]=df['timestamp'].apply(split_timestamp)
```

Output:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    timestamp  days hours minutes seconds
0  1219376117  1219    37      61      17
1  1219376118  1219    37      61      18
```

Comment: There is slight change in the data structure as my data is csv file. I have timestamp in 0th and 2nd column. There are x number of rows and 75 number of column. How can I access that two column and apply split_timestamp function?  
Secondly what does the ''int' object is not subscriptable' means?

Comment: I have data in 10*75 data format.    'df = pd.read_csv('SensorsAP_example.csv')'

data={'timestamp':["1219376117","1219376118"]} . How can I apply on my data as your data is dict?

Comment: I am trying to simulate your data. I have created an example with one column "timestamp" (replace this what you have in your data).
In your case you use the code starting from #5 i.e `def split_timestamp(s):`.

Answer (score 1):

another option is using `str.extract` method:

```
df['time_tow'] = df['timestamp'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d*)').agg(list,1)

>>> df
'''
    timestamp            time_tow
0  1219376117  [1219, 37, 61, 17]
1  1219376118  [1219, 37, 61, 18]
```

Comment: But how to do with big csv file as I am getting an error of "'int' object is not subscriptable"?

I have data frame of 9*75 format csv file.

Comment: @VimsRocz could you add an example of your data and the expected output to your question?